# How to "copy" an array operation to another array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is probably a simple question, but I have two arrays of approx 1000 elements each, they are called `posXArray` and `posYArray`. I want to sort `posYArray` numerically (lowest number first) but I want the elements of `posXArray` to have the same operation applied to them...

For example, if element [56] of `posYArray` is the smallest one , I want element [56] of `posXArray` to also be moved to [0].

How is this implemented in Java in an easy/good way?

Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class like:

```
public class XYPos implements Comparable<XYPos> {
    int x;
    int y;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(XYPos o) {
        int res = this.y - o.y;
        if(res == 0) {
            res = this.x - o.x;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then:

1. convert your 2 arrays into one array of `XYPos`
2. sort it
3. update your 2 original arrays with the values in the sorted array

Answer (score 8):

Since the arrays seem to contain X and Y coordinates, perhaps a better choice is to create a coordinate class containing both values, implement `Comparable` and just have a single array to sort using the built-in algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `Integer[] idx` of the same length and fill it with the numbers 0 to 999 (or whatever), then sort this array using a comparator that does

```
public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
  return posYArray[a] - posYArray[b];
}
```

This will give you an array of indexes into the other arrays, i.e. the smallest Y value will be `posYArray[idx[0]]` and its corresponding X will be `posXArray[idx[0]]`, etc. If you don't want to maintain the indirection you could re-order the original arrays by the `idx` values.

If you're doing this sort of thing regularly you may wish to look at [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) which provides Collection and Comparator types that operate directly on primitive types such as `int`, avoiding the need to box and unbox Integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement any sorting algorithm of your choice, do the comparation check on the first (posXArray) only, and then swap position of elements in both arrays at the same time.

Comment: It's certainly a possibility and it would work - easy: i think so, good: agreed, it isn't (in fact i voted for one of the answers suggesting to create a class) :)